# Word 2013 Equation Matrix Partition

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, equation-editor

Is there anyway to create a matrix like below one when entering an equation?

[image: matrix partition]

I did this matrix using the Microsoft Equation 3.0, but I would like to do it using the (for me, better) Equation Editor from Word 2013.

The only thing I would like to know is how/if it is possible to add the horizontal and vertical lines in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2016, I can only find a way to draw a line, and then place it over the matrix carefully. You can then set the layout option on the line to be in front or behind the text.

Not the most brilliant way, I know.

[image: place line on matrix]

Comment: I tried doing that, but the problem of drawing the line in front of the text makes it a floating object, which means I have to anchor it to a line. If I anchor it to the equation line, the equation changes to an inline equation (it changes it size) and if I anchor it to another line, then I can't guarantee the line and the matrix will always move together as I edit the document.

Comment: See the attached image.In the one on the left, the drawn line is anchored to the next line and, on the right, is anchored in the equation line.
[Line in word](https://i.imgsafe.org/de624e98a8.png).
The one on the right puts the equation inline, so it becomes "smaller"